# Why is my desktop app not posting data to my webpage?

Tags: asp.net, desktop-application

I am trying to post data from my desktop app to my webpage.

Here is the code for posting data

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:2524/HomeLogin.aspx");
httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MAC="+ lblMAC.Text.Trim());
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
using (var requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}
```

On the page load of my `ASP.NET` Webpage I am runnning this app and trying to get the value from it.
Here is my code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\Default Company Name\\MACSetup\\MAC.exe") ;
txtUsername.Text = Request.QueryString["MAC"];
```

I am not able to get the data.No error is thrown as well.I think I might be missing something.

Can anyone help me with this?

Any suggestions are welcome?

Answer (score 0):

Request.QueryString only works if you are using GET. With a POST you should use Request.Params.

Comment: It did not work , can it be an issue because the url might not be correct?

Comment: @priyankpatel what do your IIS logs tell you about requests made to the web server? and why are you running it on a non-standard port?

Comment: Is the HomeLogin.aspx even called? Can you attach to w3wp.exe and place a break point?

Comment: @TZHX Can you just explain me what I am doing wrong?I am not getting your point.

Comment: @Quirijn Ya I am not sure whether it is called , how can I check that?Any suggestions.

Comment: @Priyank Maybe the easiest way is to add 'System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()' to the code behind of your aspx, right at the start.